# How to keep vim from adding indentation to strings?

Tags: string, bash, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I want to be able to `gg=G` on my bash scripts, or some variation of auto-format that won't obstruct a simple echo.

I have a feeling that something like this isn't an issue, I just haven't discovered the proper way to either:

1. echo a string properly for this scenario
2. issue the proper command for the job

If anyone could aid me, it'd be much appreciated.

What I type:

```
someFun()
{
    echo "Some really long string that is going to be automatically
    indented.";
}
```

What I see on the prompt

```
>./someFun  
Some really long string that is going to be automatically
    indented.
```

Comment: How about "Some really long string that is going to be automatically "  
"indented."

Comment: NOT indenting the second part of string will be definitely confusing. Either put everything on same line, or use `echo "First part..."\<ENTER>"Second part"` However, this will not help for `here documents`.

Comment: There has to be something native in VIM, like some sort of regex that would remain unobtrusive to the code...

It would take less time to write a separate prettyFormat.script and just override the bind to my customized formation. I'm hesitant, because I believe in the power of VIM ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can either concatenate strings like this:

```
echo "Some really long string that is going to be automatically" \
"indented."
```

either turn off indentation:

```
:setlocal noautoindent
:setlocal nosmartindent
```

Comment: I believe this is the same response as above, albeit, better styled.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, any arguments or heads up?
 This will kinder to the needs of a project
that requires flexibility, including:

1. not being affected by textwidth=? of a multi-user environment
2. not being affected by auto-[indent|format]* (vim, gedit, notepad++, w/e)
3. avoiding unpredictable output by having full control

where these aren't reliable:
**cat << EOF ... EOF**    or      **escaping echo with "\"**

I made a file /usr/bin/yell

```
printTrueString()
{    
    local args=$@;
    echo $args;
    unset args;
}

printTrueString "$@";
exit 0
```

and now...

```
sumFun()
{      
    #auto-indent all you want VIM or w/e!...
    yell "hello mad
    world"

    #just like echo -e 
    yell -e "hello\nmad\nworld"        
}  
sumFun;
exit 0

#stays on one line, where the echo would split     
>hello mad world
>hello
mad
world
```

you could do more like ... extend echo with this as a builtin...

Answer (score 0):

Byter, here's a more proper way to achieve what you are after, along with some tips for any other starters.

First of all, you shouldn't go stashing your own shells in just any old place, especially /usr/bin. If you have a custom app I suggest storing it in **/opt** or /usr/local/bin if you must.

Secondly, this particular shell, shouldn't be a prerequisite to any of your apps, it doesn't serve a purpose different from what's already available.

Instead, see these examples:

**PROBLEM>**

```
foo()
{
    echo "A string that gets affected by auto-format, is a pretty long
    string";
}

$foo
>A string that gets affected by auto-format, is a pretty long
    string
```

**SOLUTION>**

```
foo()
{
    longString='A really long
    \nstring';
    echo -e $longString

}

$foo
>A really long
string
```

**OR**
use **cat EOF | EOL** , which will work for you if you
specify no indentation with a hyphen "-" see:

```
foo()
{
    cat <<-EOL
    really long
    string 
    EOL
}    

$foo
>really long
string
```

**In Conclusion>** This solves your problem by providing a non-obtrusive way to use strings in bash.